# Redshift SQL - select part of a string

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I would like to select a part of a string in sql. The column contains a url adress and there is always a 
id in the url, something like:

```
submissionGuid=8bb76d2e-d940-4f81-8f99-5ddf80741a05
```

The id is always 36 chars and I want to extract it from the url. In most cases it is the last part of the url but sometimes not in all cases. If it is not the last part of the url than it is followed by `&...`

I tried with the `right()` function but in some cases this does not work because the `submissionGuid`is not the last part of the url.

Comment: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-substring/

Answer (score 2):

The question was originally tagged Postgres only.  This answers the original question.

You can use `regexp_matches()`:

```
select (regexp_matches(str, 'submissionGuid=(.{32})'))[1]
```

You can be more specific about the format of the GUID, but 32 characters is a good place to start.

Comment: `REGEXP_MATCHES()` is a PostgreSQL function unsupported by Redsfhit, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html

Comment: @SomeBruh . . . When I answered the question it was tagged Postgres only.  You can look at the edit history.

Comment: No worries. Just pointing out to save future reader's time :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Substring and charindex functions;

```
Declare @txt varchar(100)
Set @TXT = 'kjaskjdhfaskjhfkjhfaksjdhf&GUID=thisisa36charstring*****************&andcarryingon'

select substring(@TXT,charindex('Guid=',@TXT)+5,36)
```

Comment: I don't think that syntax is used in Amazon Redshift?

Comment: I'm not sure about the sample code I provided BUT according to the Amazon Redshift documentation both the SubString and CharIndex functions used in my solution are supported as shown.

Answer (score 0):

#### Regular Expression

The expression you should use is `submissionGuid=([^&]*)`.

`()` is the capture group that captures the string you wish to extract.

`[^&]` is a negation class matches any character but `'&'`

`*` matches between **zero** and **unlimited** times. The maching ends whenever the end is reached or met the character in the negation class, in this case is `'&'`.

### Redshift SQL

`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, 'submissionGuid=([^&]*)', 0, 1, 'e')`

The query extract the capture group.

`0` means starting to search from position 0.

`1` means to find the first occurrence.

`e` means to return the sub-string.

Documentation: [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html)